# Laravel: How to start a session?

Tags: php, laravel, session

```
public function login(Request $request)
    {   
        $input = $request->all();
   
        $this->validate($request, [
            'email' => 'required|email',
            'password' => 'required',
        ]);
   
        if(auth()->attempt(array('email' => $input['email'], 'password' => $input['password']), $request->remember))
        {
            if (auth()->user()->role_name == 1) {
                return redirect()->route('admin.home');
            }else{
                return redirect()->route('home');
            }
        }else{
            return redirect()->route('login')
                ->with('error','Email-Address And Password Are Wrong.');
        }
          
    }
```

how to start a session?
this is where I copy the codehttps://www.itsolutionstuff.com/post/laravel-8-multi-auth-authentication-tutorialexample.html

Comment: What do you want to put in the session?

Comment: I'm doing a project "E-Commerce" and I'm in the part where i need to add to cart. and i think i still don't have a session..

Comment: Ok see my answer, I edited. Just put the cart variable in the session and use it anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you want to cart information in the session.  First, You define a session as named "cart":

```
$cart = ...
Session::set('cart', $cart);
```

or

```
$cart = ...
Session::put('cart', $cart);
```

And then get it anywhere:

```
$value = Session::get('cart');
return $value;
```